# Resolving conflicts when merging release -> master

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm trying to follow git flow. Somehow I end up with conflict when merging `release -> master`.

```
+<<<<<<< destination:0632e01db317e3a4278fe08d4792da16b44af267
   "version": "0.11.0",
+=======
+  "version": "0.12.0",
+>>>>>>> source:e3ef91821bb20497449edc85049daa9e3398d8bf
```

What is the best strategy to resolve it? Resolving conflicts when you merge release into develop/master doesn't seem to be right, does it?

Comment: Are you trying to merge release into master or vice versa, also which branch is ahead?

Comment: If you're following git flow, shouldn't you merge `release` into `develop`, then `develop` into `master`?

Comment: @AlexKven if I understand it correctly, develop is never merged into master. https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/git-flow/git-flow.png
The code ends up in master either via the release of hotfix branches.

Comment: @alex.mironov Ah yes, that is correct. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

A merge conflict with merging a `release` into `master` is definitely possible if you merged a `hotfix` branch into `master`. The best way to solve this would be to also merge the `hotfix` into the `release` branch, since the release should have it anyway.

Another possibility is if you made another `release` branch concurrently with the current release and merged it into `master` out of order with the current `release`. A good way to fix that would be probably to merge the releases, or reorganize the changes between the releases.

Comment: What would you do if the hotfix branch only applies to `master` (like a revert) and cannot apply to the release or feature branch from `develop`?

Answer (score 2):

You should be pulling `master` into your `release` branch, resolving the conflict, and then pushing the resolution.  Now you will not have any conflicts to resolve for the merge.

You can do this with a merge, or a rebase:

- `git pull origin master`
- `git rebase origin/master`

Depending on your workflow, you should be bringing `master` into your pre-`release` branches earlier, and resolving the conflicts in your lowest branches.

Comment: So if your not a solo dev you may NOT want to rebase release branxh, right?

Answer (score 0):

You always have to resolve any conflicts when you merge, independend of the direction. Otherwise the merge result will not compile.

If you have any changes in release which are not yet in develop/master then you can merge release to develop/master.

If you look at the Diagramm for git flow eg at https://lucamezzalira.com/2014/03/10/git-flow-vs-github-flow/ there are regular merges from release to develop and master.